# R not downloading total tar.gz using download.file

Tags: r

I am trying to download a 286 mb tarball (tar.gz) from ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd_hcn.tar.gz (You have to be registered to try it). I am able to download the whole 286 mb when using a browser (firefox), but when I try to download in R, I get varying sizes of files. I can't ever get the whole 286 mb. Any reason for this behavior?

Here is my R code.

```
tb = "ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd_hcn.tar.gz"
tempfile = paste(path,"/ghcnd_hcn.tar.gz",sep="") # temporary file name
download.file(tb,destfile = tempfile,replace = TRUE) ## download data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can download the whole file in R without problems but it is quite slow to download.

Maybe a time-out issue?

You can also try different values to the method parameter for download.file()

```
download.file(tb,destfile = tempfile, method = "curl", replace = TRUE)
file.size(tempfile)
```

```
download.file(tb,destfile = tempfile, method = "wget", replace = TRUE)
file.size(tempfile)
```

Comment: Thanks. It was timing out on my end. I ended up using the following code because I couldn't get download.file to finish: `tb = "ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd_hcn.tar.gz"
tempfile = paste(rootPath,"/ghcnd_hcn.tar.gz",sep="") 
f = CFILE(tempfile,mode="wb")
curlPerform(url=tb,writedata=f@ref,verbose=TRUE)
close(f)`